# find explicit formula for sequence and prove it is correct

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

$a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ is integer sequence defined recursively by

$1)a_1=0$

$2)$ for $n\gt 1$, $a_n=1+a_{\lceil{n\over 2}\rceil}$

Find an explicit formula for $a_n$ and prove it is correct.

Formula is $a_n=\lceil{\log_2(n)}\rceil$.  Base case is $n=2:a_2=1+a_1=1=\log_2(2)$.$\space\space$Assume true for $1\lt k\le n$.$\space\space$Then $a_{n+1}=1+a_{\lceil{{n+1}\over 2}\rceil}\space$ where $\lceil{{n+1}\over 2}\rceil$ must fall within the range of $k$ for $n\gt 1$.$\space\space$So $a_{n+1}=1+a_{\lceil{{n+1}\over 2}\rceil}=1+\lceil{\log_2({{n+1}\over 2})}\rceil=1+\lceil{\log_2(n+1)}\rceil-\lceil{1}\rceil=\lceil{\log_2(n+1)}\rceil$ and that completes the proof by Mathematical Induction Strong/Alternative form.

In the same way it can be shown the $a_n=\log_2(n)$.  This proof is incorrect.  The correct proof separates the cases of $n+1$ into $2^m$ and $2^m+r$. $r,m\in Z^+$, $0\lt r \lt 2^m$.  After the inductive assumption is made.  Why?  Why is the above proof incorrect?  thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that log(2) is not equal to 1 unless you are talking about logarithm "base 2".  If so you should say that.  "log" without any other notation can mean log base 10 or natural log but not log base 2.  But then your formula would give $a_8= 3$ when it should be 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base of the logarithm should be $2$.

> Why is the above proof incorrect?

Because the following part is not correct :

> So $a_{n+1}=1+a_{\lceil{{n+1}\over 2}\rceil}=1+\lceil{\log({{n+1}\over 2})}\rceil=1+\lceil{\log(n+1)}\rceil-\lceil{1}\rceil=\lceil{\log(n+1)}\rceil$

It should be the following :
$$a_{n+1}=1+a_{\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\rceil}=1+\left\lceil\log\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil\right\rceil\tag1$$

Now whether $n+1$ is of the form $2^m$ or not matters.

If $n+1=2^m$, then
$$(1)=1+\left\lceil\log(2^{m-1})\right\rceil=1+m-1=m=\lceil\log(n+1)\rceil$$

If $n+1=2^m+r$ where $0\lt r\lt 2^m$, then
$$(1)=1+\left\lceil\log\left\lceil\frac{2^m+r}{2}\right\rceil\right\rceil=1+m=\lceil\log(n+1)\rceil$$